# Internet connection cuts off every few second in Linux Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking

I use Ubuntu on a laptop and I'm having a problem with my Internet connection. My connection cuts off every few seconds but I still look like I'm connected to the Internet. I tried logging out and logging back in, rebooting the laptop, re-entering the Wi-Fi password and even changing the DNS servers but it doesn't seem to work.

Update:
The wifi device the laptop uses is "`RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter`"

Also, doing continous pings (to google.com) outputs "`From voldemort-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X415EA-X415EA (192.168.1.4) icmp_seq=452 Destination Host Unreachable`" after a while. And after a few seconds getting this output I get higher pings and this loops like this.

And lastly, I didn't found anything weird in `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: What happens if you do continuous pings, or better, use MTR?    What Wifi hardware are you using (including your laptop make or the WIFI hardware in it) You havn't really provided enough information for us to help you, but my guess is you are using a badly supported WIFI chipset (which is not hopeless, often you can fix it with appropriate driver or driver options)

Comment: You might want to see if there's anything useful in /var/log/syslog.

Comment: Updated the question @davidgo

Comment: Updated the question @MiG